# Get socket and pipe name in CentOS

Tags: bash, sockets, pipe, proc, stat

Basically, I want to get socket and pipe owners starting from a PID located in the /proc/PID/fd/ directory using the "stat" command:

```
lrwx------ 1 root root 64 dic 23 17:52 0 -> socket:[9790]
l-wx------ 1 root root 64 dic 23 17:52 1 -> /var/log/messages
l-wx------ 1 root root 64 dic 23 17:52 2 -> /var/log/secure
lr-x------ 1 root root 64 dic 23 17:52 3 -> /proc/kmsg
l-wx------ 1 root root 64 dic 23 17:52 4 -> /var/log/maillog
l-wx------ 1 root root 64 dic 23 17:52 5 -> /var/log/cron
```

How could I use "stat" to get each socket owner when I just have the socket name (socket:[9790]) instead of its symbolic reference (0,1,2...)?

Thanks for your answer!

Comment: StackOverflow's scope is limited to *writing code*.  [unix.se] or [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/) are more appropriate for questions about using standard UNIX tools.

Answer (score 1):

For this `lsof` is much better.

You can use `lsof -i -a -p $PID`.

There is a similar question on the unix hub on the StackExchange.

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/235979/how-do-i-find-out-more-about-socket-files-in-proc-fd

I think that should solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think that you can do this with one simple `stat` instruction. Instead you could try to utilize `find` in order to search for symbolic links an then print them formatted. You can then, e.g., pipe the result to `grep` and `cut` to filter for the information you need:

```
find /proc/PID/fd/ -type l -printf '%u %l\n' 2>/dev/null|grep "socket:[9790]"|cut -d' ' -f1
```

You can use `find`'s options (`-mindepth`, `-maxdepth`) in order to determine how deep it shall descend into subfolders for its search. If you want the owner's UID instead of the username then use `%U` instead of `%u` in `-printf`.